# json null pointer error in async task

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

i have a forget password activity that connects to the mysql database and generates a new password. however; the json object is always returning a null pointer exception. the php script has an html form for testing, and it's functioning perfectly so the error is for sure in the java code.

here's the Json Parser class:

```
package test.example.com.test;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }
    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

here's the AsyncTask:

```
class ForgetPass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(forg1.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Generating New Password...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String Email;

        Email = etMailfrpass.getText().toString();

        try {

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", Email));
            JSONObject json5 = js.makeHttpRequest(
                    FORGET_URL, "POST", params);

           // Log.d("Ibrahim forget pass", "Ibrahim forget pass");
            success = json5.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                //Log.d("Password generated", json5.toString());
                pDialog.dismiss();

                return json5.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
              //  Log.d("generation Failure!", json5.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json5.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url1) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url1 != null) {
            Toast.makeText(forg1.this, file_url1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

here's the log, error is at json.getInt

```
05-08 11:12:28.336  16229-16554/test.example.com.test E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value fetet of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-08 11:12:28.336  16229-16554/test.example.com.test W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa5228)
05-08 11:12:28.346  16229-16554/test.example.com.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at test.example.com.test.forg1$ForgetPass.doInBackground(forg1.java:107)
            at test.example.com.test.forg1$ForgetPass.doInBackground(forg1.java:73)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume something went wrong so this part returns null in `jObj`:

```
// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
// return JSON String
return jObj;
```

now your `AsyncTask` tries to call `getString()` method in returned `jObj` which is null by itself (**whenever success is 1 or not**):

```
    if (success == 1) {
        //Log.d("Password generated", json5.toString());
        pDialog.dismiss();

        return json5.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
    } else {
      //  Log.d("generation Failure!", json5.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
        return json5.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

    }
```

and here you go with NPE.